# In Bixby, is there any way to display the images in image-picker in a particular order or sort it by image name?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm trying to display few images to the user for them to select any one of the images and I want the images to be in particular order or to be sorted according to their name. But each time the selection screen loads the images seems to be randomized.

This is how I passed the images:

```
  default-init {
    intent {
      goal: Image
      value: Image {
        url: viv.core.Url("/images/img1.png")
      }
      value: Image {
        url: viv.core.Url("/images/img2.png")
      }
      value: Image {
        url: viv.core.Url("/images/img3.png")
      }
      value: Image {
        url: viv.core.Url("/images/img4.png")
      }
      value: Image {
        url: viv.core.Url("/images/img5.png")
      }
      value: Image {
        url: viv.core.Url("/images/img6.png")
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the input-view:

```
  input-view {
    match: Image (this) {
      to-input: SelectImage 
    }

    message {
       template (Choose any image?)
    }

    render {
      image-picker (this) {
        size (Medium)
    }
  }
}
```

I want them to display in the given order or to be sorted out according to their name(which is the same in this case). What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you list value in the action model, it is not in any order and would be random.

An easy solution is to create a separate action with no input, and use that action in default init. Then in the linked JS function, return an array of image objects. The display order would be the array index order.

Change default-init section

```
    default-init {
    intent {
      goal: GetDefaultImage
    }
```

Add action GetDefaultImage

```
action(GetDefaultImage) {
  type(Search) 
  output(Image)
}
```

Linked JS file (link it in your endpoints file)

```
module.exports.function = function getDefaultImage () {
  var result = []
  // result should be in the format of result[0].url = 'imageUrl1'
  //                                   result[1].url = 'imageUrl2'
  return result;
}
```